# can't remove more than one table row, without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, tablerow

In MVC, I constructed a table in a view, by iterating over a 'List' of a viewmodel.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr id="row-@item.name">
    <td>
        @item.type
    </td>
    <td >
        @Html.ActionLink((string)item.name, "Download", "FileUpload", new { rout = item.rout, fileName = item.name }, null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.size
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="delete-file" del-url="@item.delete_url">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

when I load the page, I get a list of files, with a 'delete' link for each.

I implemented with jQuery a basic 'remove row' method:

```
$('#delete-file').click(function() {
    var delUrl = $(this).attr('del-url');
    $.post(delUrl, null, removeRow(),'json')
});

function removeRow() {
   $($('#delete-file').closest('tr')).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

When I click 'delete' on one of the file rows, it performs well, but then, if I click on another (delete), nothing happens. No file is deleted on server, and the row is not removed, as if it's being ignored completely.

Comment: You have errors in your js. The anonymous function isn't closed, and the line isn't ended. http://jsfiddle.net/7Z4C4/

Comment: I recommend using `data-del-url=""` and using `.data('del-url')`. Custom attributes are invalid like you have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `class="delete-file"` instead of `id="delete-file"` - and of course the corresponding `$(".delete-file")` selector as well.

IDs are meant to be unique per document, and your code binds the handler to the first `id="delete-file"` element.

Comment: tnks! BTW, although it's a simple one, how should one debug situations like these and jquery at all?

Answer (score 4):

Here is you solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/irpm/enEAt/1/

the javascript is:

```
$('.delete-file').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});​
```

Comment: @sergel When I refresh the page after i remove the row, it comes back again. I wanted to remove the row permanently from the row. How is that possible??

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the default action of the `<a>` element, and use the correct selectors

```
$('.delete-file').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self=this,
        delUrl = $(this).attr('del-url');
    $.post(delUrl, function() {
        $(self).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
    },'json');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$.post(delUrl, null, removeRow(),'json');
```

simply equivalent to this:

```
$.post(delUrl, null, undefined, 'json');
```

as `removeRow()` function does not return anything. Change that line to this:

```
$.post(delUrl, null, removeRow,'json');   //Without '()' after 'removeRow'
```

And your `removeRow` function will not work as you expected I guess. That function will hide all the rows, but you need to hide only that one, which 'delete-file' is clicked. So you need to pass reference of that row to `removeRow` function. Here is one way of doing that:

```
$('#delete-file').click(function() {
   var delUrl = $(this).attr('del-url');
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   $.post(delUrl, null, function(){
       removeRow($row);
   },'json')
});

function removeRow($row) {   $row.fadeOut('slow');   }
```

Comment: +1 The point is that `removeRow` *references* the function, while `removeRow()` executes it. Executing it is not desired. Referencing it is.